# Create triplets from list of words

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of words, something like this:

```
['The', 'Quick', 'Brown', 'Fox', 'Jumps', 'Over', 'The', 'Lazy', 'Dog']
```

I'd like to generate a list of lists, with each array containing 3 of the words, but with a possible triplet for each one. So it should look something like this:

```
['The', 'Quick', 'Brown']
['Quick', 'Brown', 'Fox']
['Brown', 'Fox', 'Jumps']
```

and so on.  What would be the best way to get this result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> words
['The', 'Quick', 'Brown', 'Fox', 'Jumps', 'Over', 'The', 'Lazy', 'Dog']
>>> [words[i:i+3] for i in range(len(words) - 2)]
[['The', 'Quick', 'Brown'], ['Quick', 'Brown', 'Fox'], ['Brown', 'Fox', 'Jumps'], ['Fox', 'Jumps', 'Over'], ['Jumps', 'Over', 'The'], ['Over', 'The', 'Lazy'], ['The', 'Lazy', 'Dog']]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
b = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(len(a)-2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

With sliceable sequences such as lists, the answers already given work fine.  For the general case in which the words come in any iterable (be it a sequence, a file, whatever):

```
def NbyN(seq, N=3):
  it = iter(seq)
  window = [next(it) for _ in range(N)] 
  while True:
    yield window
    window = window[1:] + [next(it)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing why you want to do this or how many times it needs to be done, I'd say just slice it.